How to verify a token on solana
I've a client who is asking me to verify his token on solana what is said is "Token verification is simply going to register the token with the Solana ecosystem so it shows up as a verified token when people are researching it"
I've done some research but couldn't find a solution, like on ETH chain we can verify the contract is there any way we can do so on Sol?

Pulling directly from the Jupiter docs, a verified token on their lists meets the following requirements,

Be at least 21 days old
Have daily volume of more than 10K
Have a market cap of more than 100K
Have unique metadata (Symbol and Name do not duplicate another project on the community list)
Have more than 500 unique holders

docs: https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/get-your-token-on-jupiter
The requirements for getting on the community list are less strict

500+ holders,
>100k mcap,
>10k 24 hour volume.
It is also important for your project to have a meaningful and credible presence.

link to page with these details ->  https://www.jupresear.ch/t/faq-jupiter-community-tag/23074

I just want that it shows up as a verified token when people are researching it
